# i18n Currency and Date formatting for Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel-4, internationalization

This is problem a simple problem but I am having a mental block on this. I am working on a project that has users in 7 countries currently. All are English speaking countries so many of the words are the same minus some like 'postal code' and 'cheques' which I already figured out. Problem I'm having is how can you switch formatting of dates from m/d/Y to Y-m-d? Can you set those up in the lang files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absense of a database of locale information (typically these are based on http://cldr.unicode.org), a common solution is treat the date format as just another translatable string.  If you were using gettext for your translations, you could use:

```
echo date(gettext('j F Y'));
```

As a courtesy to your translators, you might want to give them some clues.  Again, with gettext, you might use:

```
echo date(/* Long date format.  See http://php.net/date */ gettext('j F Y'));
```